# How to match regex avoid parentheses inside parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I have string expression like this

```
CONTAIN("A(ASDFASDF)","MAKLOON") &&  !CONTAIN("THIS IS THE (STRING) ","MAKLON") &&  !CONTAIN("ASDFASDF","MAKLUN") &&  ("121"=="" ||  121.00=="" ||  121.0=="")
```

I want to match only the result like  this :

```
1. CONTAIN("A(ASDFASDF)","MAKLOON") 
2. CONTAIN("THIS IS THE (STRING) ","MAKLON")
3. CONTAIN("ASDFASDF","MAKLUN")
```

I have try with this regex but the match only this :

```
CONTAIN\(.*?\)
```

Result

```
1. CONTAIN("A(ASDFASDF)
2. CONTAIN("THIS IS THE (STRING)
3. CONTAIN("ASDFASDF","MAKLUN")
```

How to solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: Can there be a `")` inside the text you want to capture? Or are you 100% sure they will always end with those two characters? For example: `CONTAIN("HELLO",")WORLD(")`.

Comment: I think this is simple solution first for my case, although this is not perfect solution. Maybe in my future development that case will be exist. . If you have the other solution. please write here. regards.

Comment: Added a slightly more robust solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly enhanced version, which allows the inner string to have parenthesis. It's not perfect either, but probably a bit more secure:

```
CONTAIN\(".*?", ?".*?"\)
```

*Brief explanation*: It matches `CONTAIN(`, then any character until it finds `","` or `", "` (optional space, remove `?` if you will never have a space there), then again any character until the final `")`. The `?` after the `*` is necessary to make it match as little as possible. Otherwise, `.*` would match as much as possible, from the first to the last `CONTAIN` string.

Besides matching what you mention in your post, it will also match:

```
CONTAIN("HEL()LO",")WORLD(")
CONTAIN(")HELLO(",")WORLD(")
```

And will **not** match an invalid strings like these, which are matched by the other proposed solutions:

```
CONTAIN("HELLO",")WORLD()     // partial match
CONTAIN(")
CONTAIN(""")
```

I tried to do some more complex regex to match the number of quotes or parenthesis, but I think you don't need such complexity, unless your string may have escaped quotes, like `\"` or `""`.

If you won't get any of those invalid strings or strange strings, you may be good enough with the other simpler regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern: `CONTAIN\(.*?"\)`

Comment: Thanks. It's works..  Can you explain the `"` in the regex pattern does?

Comment: Instead of using only 1 parentheses **)**, we'll use **")** as the anchor for pattern matching.

Comment: Beware this won't work with a string like `CONTAIN("HELLO",")WORLD(")`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the regular expression you're looking for would be: `(CONTAIN\(\".+\"\))`. By including the `\"` you get all of the characters inside the quotes instead of ending at the first instance of a ')'.

Comment: I try this and get all string whole till I get `)`. I want in  lazy in regex

Comment: Right, that `.+` will select as much as possible. You need a `?` there.